How to obtain open loop transfer function for a feedback system with feedforward?
This might be a silly question but I am really struggling with it.
I want to plot the bode plot for a few systems and compare the gain and phase margins. I understand that it is done using the open loop transfer function (OLTF) which is just the transfer function in the feedforward path (in the case of unity feedback). However, this is only true for the following case:

Here, C is a controller and P is the plant.
If I had that case, I would simply plot the bode plot for C*P and see the gain and phase margins. However, I have this:

where the input of one system contributes to the input of another system via a feedforward path. For simplicity, I've considered only systems here but in the actual problem, I have N of these systems connected like this. Anyway, I am not sure how I go about finding the OLTF for the first system. If I consider the u_2 to be a disturbance, the first system reduces to simple feedback which doesn't give me anything new for plotting bode plot although the system is clearly different.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

For the first figure, when you find OLTF you will notice that r does not influence it. Only signals "in the loop" has influence on OLTF. Keep this in mind.
In the second figure with two loops, u2 depends on r and y2. Since no signal in the first loop influences either r or y2, neither of them are "in the loop" as far as the loop involving y1 is concerned.
You are right in that

... the first system reduces to simple feedback which doesn't give me anything new ...

If it was the case that, y1, u1 or e1 had a connection to the bottom loop, then you could have done some block diagram rearrangement (or reduction) and found a new, different, OLTF.
Alternate way
Using block diagram reduction techniques, move the summing junction of u1  to the left side of C. Now the two summing junctions are nearby and they too can be interchanged and u1 now falls "outside the loop" just like r1.
edit
If you are finding OLTF for the bottom loop, you can neglect the tap-off point at u2 as there is no return signal flow from the top loop back to the bottom loop. Ideally, you should do it by block diagram transformations or some other mathematical method rather than "inspection". But intuition is still good to have.
edit
Since we are talking about transfer functions and OLTF, it is assumed that all the blocks in the block diagram are LTI systems. Otherwise, the signal u2 can change the operating point of the blocks in the top loop and change the effective OLTF of the loop.

Thanks @AJN. Now I am wondering whether it is as easy as easy as just following the signal flow from the reference to the output. For example, if I wanted to find the OLTF for the bottom loop i.e. from r2 (which is the same as r) to y2, would I end up with two branches originating from u2 where one of the branches will go to the top loop to y1 through P and the other one to y2 through bottom P?

If you are finding OLTF for the bottom loop, you can neglect the tap-off point at u2 as there is no return signal flow from the top loop back to the bottom loop. Ideally, you should do it by block diagram transformations or some other mathematical method rather than "inspection". But intuition is still good to have.
